# ruby install yob pdf reader

Tags: ruby, pdf

I'm trying to install the yob pdf reader: https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader#readme

I'm following the directions there and do:

```
gem install pdf-reader
```

and that reports success.

I place a pdf in my directory, name it `1.pdf`.

Then I create a script that has the following code:

```
reader = PDF::Reader.new("1.pdf")
```

when I run that script I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant PDF (NameError)
```

Googling it hasn't been very successful so far.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Which version of ruby are you using?

Comment: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [x86_64-linux]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a pure ruby script, you may be missing the following at the beginning:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pdf-reader'
```

You can also specify the version of the gem that you want to require, in case you have multiple versions installed:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'pdf-reader', "~> 0.10.0"
require 'pdf-reader'
```

Comment: thats what i googled, but then i got error "`require': no such file to load -- pdf/reader (LoadError)". Its like im missing some gem, but i dont know which one.. or something.

Comment: @Hermann I edited my answer, rubygems is loaded by default in 1.9 but not in 1.8.

Comment: thanks for that, that was great help. now im onto the next unexplained error "`initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)". Which doesnt make any sense because that installation manual says it should be done like this.

Comment: bounty of 50 if u can help me with that one.

Comment: You most likely have a gem conflict. Could you post the output of `gem list` (ideally in a new question)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386042/ruby-yob-pdf-reader-wrong-argument-quantity