# Ruby yob pdf reader, wrong argument quantity

Tags: ruby, pdf

I'm trying to install the yob pdf reader: https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader#readme

My script has the following code:

```
reader = PDF::Reader.new("1.pdf")
```

when I run that script I get the following error:

```
`initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

Which doesn't make any sense because the directions say this should be done this way.

How do I solve this?

p.s.

`gem list` command produces:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
Ascii85 (1.0.1)
bundler (1.0.18)
columnize (0.3.4)
linecache (0.46)
nokogiri (1.5.0)
pdf-reader (0.10.0)
rbx-require-relative (0.0.5)
rdoc (3.9.4, 2.5.11)
rdoc-data (2.5.3)
ruby-debug (0.10.4)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.4)
rudebug (0.3.2)
syntax (1.0.0)
```

gem -v produces: 1.3.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely have a gem version conflict. You can specify the version of the gem that you want to require, in case you have multiple versions installed:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'pdf-reader', "~> 0.10.0"
require 'pdf-reader'
```

**Update**

I would slap myself if I could. There's nothing wrong with your setup. The instructions to use `PDF::Reader.new "my_file.pdf"` are for the git version.

Check the [examples directory](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader/tree/v0.10.0/examples) for the version 0.10.0 to get examples of how to use the library.

Comment: i put that at the top of my script but i still get the same error.

Comment: Check the examples directory for 0.10.0, the instructions you read are for the git version.

Comment: and where is the examples directory?

Comment: it works, cheers! It doesnt seem to be possible to offer the bounty.

Comment: I don't really care about the bounty. Thanks for the thought though!