# ruby on rails with gem pdf-reader: Uninitialized constant error

Tags: pdf, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

i got stuck trying to use the pdf-reader(V1.3.2) to dive in to a PDF unsing ruby on rails (ruby V1.9.3). I basicially get this as an error:

Uninitialized constant PDF::READER

I found some answers to the problem like:
[ruby install yob pdf reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384723/ruby-install-yob-pdf-reader)
but nothing really solved it.
gem is installed and in the gemfile and in the bundle-command answer

this is the library:
https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader

here is my code:

```
class UploadController < ApplicationController
require 'rubygems'
require 'pdf/reader'

def index
    render :file => 'app\views\upload\uploadfile.html.erb'
    reader = PDF::READER.new("hello.pdf")
            @pagenumbers = reader.page_count
end
def uploadFile
    @uploaded = false
    if post = Datafile.save(params[:upload])
        #render :text =>"File saved!"
        @uploaded = true

        index
else render :text =>"file not saved!"
end
end
def error_file
    render :text => "error"
    end
end
```

THX!

Answer (score 0):

solved! stupid typo! PDF::READER --> PDF::Reader